# Getting "InvalidRequestException" when trying to configure the logging settings for the AWS Network Firewall with Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am asked to use Terraform to create the network firewall. My code creates the firewall policy and firewall fine. However, it is giving me an error when trying to configure the logging settings. Here is the part of the code that creates the log groups (which works fine) and configures the firewall to use the settings (which gives me the error)

```html
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "firewall_alert_loggroup" {
  name = "/aws/networkfirewall/alertlog"
  retention_in_days = 180
  tags = {
    category = "firewall_logs"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "firewall_flow_loggroup" {
  name = "/aws/networkfirewall/flowlog"
  retention_in_days = 180
  tags = {
    category = "firewall_logs"
  }
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_logging_configuration" "firewall_alert_logging" {
  firewall_arn = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.firewall_resource.arn
  logging_configuration {
    log_destination_config {
      log_destination = {
        logGroup = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.firewall_alert_loggroup.name
      }
      log_destination_type = "CloudWatchLogs"
      log_type             = "ALERT"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_logging_configuration" "firewall_flow_logging" {
  firewall_arn = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.firewall_resource.arn
  logging_configuration {
    log_destination_config {
      log_destination = {
        logGroup = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.firewall_flow_loggroup.name
      }
      log_destination_type = "CloudWatchLogs"
      log_type             = "FLOW"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I would get this error:

```html
│ Error: 1 error occurred:
│       * adding Logging Configuration to NetworkFirewall Firewall (arn:aws:network-firewall:us-west-2:866214384033:firewall/test-fw-by-terraform): InvalidRequestException: Given logging configuration attempts to create/modify multiple log destination configs
│
│
│
│   with aws_networkfirewall_logging_configuration.firewall_alert_logging,
│   on main.tf line 235, in resource "aws_networkfirewall_logging_configuration" "firewall_alert_logging":
│  235: resource "aws_networkfirewall_logging_configuration" "firewall_alert_logging" {
│
```

The firewall_flow_logging resource is applied successfully and I verified with the web GUI. What did I do wrong with the firewall_alert_logging configuration? Thanks!